# Recursive comparison, can you point out my mistake?

Tags: python, recursion

```
def chooseBest(s):
    if len(s) == 2:
        c = cmp(s[0], s[1])
        if c == -1 or c == 0:
            return s[0]
        elif c == 1:
            return s[1]
    else:
        return chooseBest(s[1:])
```

Where 's' is a list of comparable values.

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: when you ask a question, please write your intentions explicitly. what were you trying to do? in what context?

Comment: Based on the code that is there, it seems that the purpose is to find the least element in the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were trying to recursively find the biggest element in a list of comparable values, here's how it should be done:

```
def chooseBest(s):
    if not s:
        return None
    best = chooseBest(s[1:])
    return s[0] if s[0] > best else best
```

Or even shorter:

```
def chooseBest(s):
    return max(s[0], chooseBest(s[1:])) if s else None
```

Either way, it works for built-in comparable data types. If for some reason you need to compare it with a type you defined, don't forget to make it comparable with `None`:

```
chooseBest([1, 2, 5, 3, 4])
=> 5

chooseBest(['a', 'b', 'z', 'c', 'd'])
=> 'z'
```

Comment: better edge case - `if len(s)==1: return s[0]`. no need to assume anything about the type of the content.

Comment: I don't think it's better, it'll fail if the list is empty

Comment: "best" for unknown type is undefined if the list is empty, so it can be a good idea; if you don't agree, you can return `None`.

Comment: OK, I agree with that :) I updated my answer

Comment: now you need to be able to compare with `None` (which you generally can't)

Comment: OK, that justifies an additional clarification - but nevertheless  it'll just work for built-in data types. No big deal, and still much cleaner than having to mess around with two base cases - one for the empty list, one for single-element list

Comment: In python 3 it will *not* work for anything. and the empty case can be handled one time, in a wrapper function, or not handled at all (which I think is perfectly fine), or be a 'default' parameter.

Comment: `max([])` => `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`.

Comment: Thank you both very much, I used Elazar's 'better edge case' with your implementation.  Makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

Think about whether chooseBest([x, y, z]) can ever return x.